# Gráfico com legendas sobrepostas em R [sem usar ggplot2

Tags: r, plot

Olá, meu gráfico está ficando com alguns valores sobrepostos, já tentei aumentar o gráfico não resolveu.

```
 library(RColorBrewer) #cores
cor = brewer.pal(12, "BuPu")
gen =c(1, 130, 2, 31, 1 )
labs_g =c( "Desconhecido" , "Genótipo 1", "Genótipo 2", "Genótipo 3",  "Genótipo 4")
val_g =c("0,5% (1)", "77,3 %(130)", "2,9%(2)", "18,5%(31)", "0,5% (1)" )
pie(gen, col= cor, main =  'Genótipo', labels = c(val_g), radius = .7 )
legend("bottomright",legend=labs_g, bty="n",fill= cor)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: 1) Falta o vetor `cor`. 2) Não consigo reproduzir o erro com os valores da pergunta. 3) Usando os valores do gráfico o erro é reprodutível, por favor edite a pergunta com esses valores.

Comment: Olá, adcionei o vetor cor e copiei os valores novamente

Comment: Não creio que seja possível. Na source de `pie`, ficheiro `pie.R` está a seguinte linha `text(1.1*P$x, 1.1*P$y, labels[i], xpd = TRUE, adj = ifelse(P$x < 0, 1, 0), ...)`. Veja o parâmetro `adj`. É ele que controla a justificação do texto na label e não pode ser mudado pelo usuário.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(RColorBrewer) #cores
cor = brewer.pal(12, "BuPu")
gen = c(1, 130, 2, 31, 1 )
labs_g = c( "Desconhecido" , "Genótipo 1", "Genótipo 2", "Genótipo 3", "Genótipo 4")
val_g = c("0,5% (1)", "77,3 %(130)", "2,9%(2)", "18,5%(31)", "0,5% (1)")

par(xpd = TRUE)
pie(gen, col= cor, main =  'Genótipo', labels = c(val_g), radius = 0.7, clockwise = TRUE)
legend(1.3, .1, "bottomright", legend=labs_g, bty = "n", fill = cor, cex = 0.7)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]